# Jackson Wrapping Objects in List

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to create a Java library to manage the Card.v1 JSON for the Alternative Runtime Google Add-ons functions. I've gotten everything to work, but am running into some problems getting Jackson to wrap classes in the same way that the Google APIs require it.

As an example, they have a Section that has a list of Widgets, which are wrapped Text Paragraphs, Images, or Button Lists. Here is an example JSON:

```
"sections":[ {
 "widgets":[
    {
       "textParagraph":{
          "text":"Your random cat 2:"
       }
    },
    {
       "image":{
          "imageUrl":"https://cataas.com/cat"
       }
    },
    {
       "buttonList":{
          "buttons":[
             {
                "text":"Happy",
             },
             {
                "text":"Sad",
             }
          ]
       }
    }
 ]
} ]
```

I have created a `Text` class, which looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeName("textParagraph")
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class TextParagraph extends BaseWidget
{
    String text;
}
```

If I use the object mapper to write this out on its own, I get the expected JSON:

```
"textParagraph" : {
  "text" : "Testing Text"
}
```

But if I have a List and then print that, it loses the "textParagraph" wrapping.

```
{
  "widgets" : [ {
    "text" : "Testing Text"
  }, {
    "text" : "Testing Text 2"
  }, {
    "imageUrl" : "ggole.com/image.png",
    "altText" : "Image Text"
  } ]
}
```

Is there a special annotation I'm missing to wrap the list objects? I'd really like to do this without having to use any custom mappers or Wrapper classes.

Does anyone have experience here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it.

On the base class (BaseWidget), I needed to add the `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)` annotation. With that in place, the list serializes with the wrappers.